# How to for loop a button widget in flutter without using Listview

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

i want to for loop a button i'm using this code but it show an error , i'm stuck here for 1 day thank you
I want to use for loop because this data is dynamic.

````
     showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          // return object of type Dialog
          return CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: Text('Add Location'),
            actions: <Widget>[

              for (var q = 1;q<=2;q++){

              FlatButton(
                child: new Text("Location A"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  locationA = 'Location A';
                },
              ),
            }

            ],
          );
        },
      );```
````

Comment: Why don't you just make two buttons? You don't have to do a loop if you're only making two.

Comment: That data/button is dynamic

Comment: Still don't understand why you need a for loop. First off, there should be NO logic in your build method whatsoever because it can be called at any time for any reason. Keep the logic in a separate method.

Comment: Is this in a Stateless or Stateful widget?

Comment: Im using Stateful widget

Comment: BTW i'm just showing you the simple problem there's no need to show the whole logic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a simple method that hopefully fits your needs. The method returns a list that uses a loop to add items to the list. In the end, it returns the populated list.

```
showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: true,
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      // return object of type Dialog
      return CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text('Add Location'),
        actions: _getList(), // try with or without the ()'s
      );
    },
);

// the  method
List<Widget> _getList() {
  List<Widget> temp = [];
  for (var q = 1; q<=2; q++) {
    temp.add(
      FlatButton(
        child: new Text("Location A"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          locationA = 'Location A';
        },
      );
    );
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: it's a good idea but its showing type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Comment: It's work but every time i select a location it will pop to my login page :D

Comment: Well I don't know how you're implementing it. I was just giving you an example of how you could do it.